# iptables - redirecting established connections

Tags: linux, iptables

I need to reroute established TCP connection from one port to another. A connection on port 8080 needs to be rerouted to 8180.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8180
```

does the rerouting for new connections. But established connections stays on port 8080. Can it be rerouted on the fly? If not, how do I cut the connection to enforce a reconnect to the redirected port?

Likewise, when removing the redirect, can the connection be forced back to the original port (8080)?

Comment: Update: DROP does stop the data stream as required. However, the client just "hangs". A more polite way to kick clients off is by using a tcp reset : `iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` :)

Comment: also reload service (in case of nginx) can drop established connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they will not be rerouted on the fly for already established connections. NAT table in iptables uses conntrack to keep track of the established connections so they don't need to be NATed again. Actually, connection tracking is what makes Linux netfilter a "stateful" firewall. It stores all the connections (source IP, dest IP, protocol, port numbers, conn status, etc).

To enforce established connections to reconnect to different port, you can simply deny `DROP` the traffic destined to old port.

Connection tracking is fundamental to NAT as stated in [this page](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.3) of iptables documentation.